# Different results for calculating percentage in C

Tags: c, formula

I have a weird question. I started reading *Let us C* and came across a situation. 
When i give the below code, `percentage` variable, i get `0` as output, but when i modify the formula, it doesn't do that. Can someone explain why ?

```
int m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,aggregate;
float percentage;

 printf("Please enter marks of the student in 5 subjects : \n");
 scanf("%d %d %d %d %d",&m1,&m2,&m3,&m4,&m5);
 aggregate = m1+m2+m3+m4+m5;
 percentage= (aggregate/500)*100;
```

The output for above is below :

```
Please enter marks of the student in 5 subjects : 
50 50 50 50 50
The aggregate of marks obtained by the student is : 250 
The percentage of marks obtained by the student is : 0.000000*
```

But if i modify the percentage formula as below :
    percentage= aggregate/5;

I get the right output.

```
Please enter marks of the student in 5 subjects : 
50 50 50 50 50
The aggregate of marks obtained by the student is : 250 
The percentage of marks obtained by the student is : 50.000000
RUN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6s)*
```

Can someone please explain why this happens even though both are using the same formula ?

Answer (score 6):

Since `aggregate` is an int, `(aggregate/500)*100` will yield an int. Change to `(aggregate/500.0)*100` or `aggregate/5.0`

The reason `percentage= aggregate/5` "works" is pure luck. It won't with all numbers. It will give a correct result when aggregate is a multiple of 5.

Also, burn the book "Let us C". It's extremely bad.

Comment: Hi Klutt, Thank you for answering. yes, it works.Its been too long since i did this and i forgot how casting works.